# How do I loop through XML and print properly using elementtree in python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am getting every childtwo in the whole xml printed with every childone in the whole document. How do I get just the childtwos that go with the childone?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET            
tree = ET.parse("C:/Users/thisuser/Desktop/test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for ticket in root.findall('.//Parent'):
    Childone = ticket.find('.//Childone').text

    for ticket in root.findall('.//ParentTwo'):
        Childtwo = ticket.find('.//Childtwo').text

        print "Childone={Childone}, Childtwo={Childtwo}".format(Childone=Childone, Childtwo=Childtwo)
```

Result

```
ChildOne=1  ChildTwo=a
ChildOne=1  ChildTwo=b
ChildOne=1  ChildTwo=c
ChildOne=1  ChildTwo=d

ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=a
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=b
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=c
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=d
```

Desired Result

```
ChildOne=1  ChildTwo=a
ChildOne=1  ChildTwo=b

ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=c
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=d
```

XML sample

```
<Parent>
    <Childone>1</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>a</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>b</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
</Parent>

<Parent>
    <Childone>2</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>c</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>d</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Good Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. +1

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `root` in the `findall` of your second `for` loop:

```
for ticket in root.findall('.//ParentTwo'):
```

Instead, you should use `ticket` from the outer loop to limit what `ParentTwo` elements are found. (Also note I changed `ticket` to `ticket2` since you've already used `ticket`.):

```
for ticket2 in ticket.findall('.//ParentTwo'):
```

Full edited code...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("C:/Users/thisuser/Desktop/test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for ticket in root.findall('.//Parent'):
    Childone = ticket.find('.//Childone').text

    for ticket2 in ticket.findall('.//ParentTwo'):
        Childtwo = ticket2.find('.//Childtwo').text

        print "Childone={Childone}, Childtwo={Childtwo}".format(Childone=Childone, Childtwo=Childtwo)
```